# How to specify the exact number of output image frames with ffmpeg?

Tags: animation, ffmpeg

I have *N* input animation frames as images in a folder and I want to create interpolated inbetween frames to create a smoother animation of length *N * M*, i.e. for every input frame I want to create *M* output frames that gradually morph to the next frame, e.g. with the `minterpolate` filter.

In other words, I want to increase the FPS *M* times, but I am not working with time as I am **not** working with any video formats, both input and output are image sequences stored as image files.

I was trying to combine the `-r` and `FPS` options, but without success as I don't know how they work together. For example:

- I have 12 input frames.
- I want to use the `minterpolate` filter to achieve 120 frames.
- I use the command `ffmpeg -i frames/f%04d.png -vf "fps=10, minterpolate" -r 100 interpolated_frames/f%04d.png`
- The result I get is 31 output frames.

Is there a specific combination of `-r` and `FPS` I should use? Or is there another way I can achieve what I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg assigns a framerate of 25 to formats which don't have an inherent frame rate, like image sequences.

The image sequence demuxer has an option to set a framerate. And the minterpolate filter has an option for target fps.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 12 -i frames/f%04d.png -vf "minterpolate=fps=120" interpolated_frames/f%04d.png
```

Comment: Thanks! This yields 101 frames for some reason though, but if I use `-framerate 1` and `fps=12`, I get 121 frames, which is almost there.